# FreeBSD 10 hangs on CD Loader

Tags: boot, bootloader, freebsd

I'm having some problem with FreeBSD 10 installer,

I've recorded two DVD's, but when they boot, show:

> ```
>  CD Loader 1.2
>
>  Building the boot loader arguments
>  Looking up /BOOT/LOADER... Found
>  /
> ```

This bar keeps rotating forever, I let the computer on for 10 hours and nothing, I have huge HD usage and huge CD-ROM usage.

I was thinking that was a corrupted CD, but I downloaded again a second time, check the MD5SUM and make the k3b check the disk after record to make sure and this second disk had the same behavior.

Comment: I had no such issue with the amd64 version of the DVD. Maybe you could try the memstick image if your hardware supports booting from a USB flash drive.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i've tryied with a USB Stick with sucess, i've installed FreeBSD using the USB, but, still have problems booting FreeBSD 10 trought CD-ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried with a USB Stick with success. I've installed FreeBSD using a USB but still have problems booting FreeBSD 10 with CD-ROM.

If anyone has this problem, install FreeBSD from a USB stick; it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just for other people running into the same problem...

In my case the FreeBSD-10 DVD hangs on boot-loader because my DVD drive's sata-port was configured to use **AHCI** mode.

I've switched the mode to IDE in BIOS and voila! FreeBSD booted from DVD.

It seems that FreeBSD had some problems booting from DVD if the drive is connected to an AHCI-mode sata port.